# http://localhost:5173/laravel-echo-setup.js - vite config

Tags: laravel, vite

this is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/laravel-echo-setup.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    }
});
```

this is my file:
\resources\js\laravel-echo-setup.js

I run this commands:

```
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

in my blade view:

```
@vite('laravel-echo-setup.js')
```

but I got this error:

```
GET http://localhost:5173/laravel-echo-setup.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

but below url shows welcome page:

```
http://localhost:5173
```

Comment: it should be ``@vite('resources/js/laravel-echo-setup.js')``